# minimum dependencies for JasperReports

Tags: dependencies, jasper-reports

I am looking to use JasperReports 4.5.0 in a project of mine and would like to know what are the minimum dependencies for only PDF generation. I tried looking through their site and readme docs and found absolutely nothing. I also came across this [installation wiki](http://www.installationwiki.org/JasperReports) which seems very outdated (version 1.2.2). Is there any recent documentation of the required jars?

Comment: Do you mean generation with help of JasperReports API?

Comment: You can look at `pom.xml` from distribution package.

Comment: @AlexK yes. But `pom.xml` lists things like `poi` which is required if you want to generate Excel spreadsheets, which is not an intended use in my project. Edit: I see that it list that things are optional in there. Thanks never knew that before.

Comment: I think it takes you about 10 minutes to make experiment - to comment dependencies and try to launch application.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Java Swing app that uses Jasper Reports only for PDF generation. But it is version 3.7.2, not 4.5.0.

The minimum dependencies are:

- iText
- Apache Commons BeanUtils
- Apache Commons Collections
- Apache Commons Digester
- Apache Commons Logging